# Why cannot you print from within windows message queue

Tags: c, windows, conemu

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  MSG Msg;

  while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 ) {

    TranslateMessage(&Msg);

    printf("hello world \n");

    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
  }
```

(Running Windows 10 Creator's Update)

Does anyone know why this `prinf` does not work ?

It sounds like a trivial thing to be fussed about but I am doing this across thread and the lack of ability to `printf` completely threw me off. I am super curious about the internal details as to why my standard output is being ignored - and how windows is doing it.

**EDIT 1**

I am running the program on `cmd.exe` - using `ConEmu`.

**EDIT 2**

This is the build script

`C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -g -O2 -c -o main.o main.c`

`C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -Wall -g -shared -o main main.o`

**EDIT 3**

The thing that is confusing is if you :

```
  printf("hello world 1 \n");

  while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 ) {

    printf("hello world 2\n");


    TranslateMessage(&Msg);

   DispatchMessage(&Msg);
  }
```

The first message `hello world 1` prints but the second one `hello world 2` does not !

It it like the windows `API` calls is making external changes to my runtime environment :(

Comment: Are you making a console program or a Windows program? That's not much of an example to go on.

Comment: Is this from a console program, which have a console window automatically attached? And please  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you haven't created the program as a console application, or explicitly attached a console, there's nowhere for `printf` to print anything.

Comment: I do not think its a windows program if you mean running dialogue boxes and stuff.

Its bare terminal (not powershell) as in command prompt.

Comment: The problem isn't *where* you run the program from, but the *program type*. Do you have a `main` function? Do you have a `WinMain` function? How did you create the program? In what environment did you create (not run) the program? How did you build it? And please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: .. but its stdout - does windows suppress stdout or reroutes it to some other place ?

Is there a way to show stdout on the terminal ? since I am running it on the terminal.

Comment: I am building it as a bare C program, nothing fancy. This is the commands.


`C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  -Wall -g -O2 -c -o main.o main.c`

`C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  -Wall -g -shared -o main     main.o`

Comment: This isn't really the site for tutorials like this, but here's the short version: In Windows there are two types of programs: Console programs and GUI programs. Console programs have a console attached to them, with a `stdout` that writes to that console. GUI programs ***doesn't*** have a console attached to them, and therefore all output to `stdout` is discared since there's nowhere to write it.

Comment: okay thank you for that information !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude are you sure that is true , because a printf statement outside the loop prints to console but within the loop its blocked !

I do not even understand how its possible to do that externally in a running C program, since I have not seen this type of thing in linux `syscall`. Thanks for your help !

Comment: If that is indeed your whole program there is little wonder you never see printing within the loop. What are you expecting would be causing `GetMessage` to even *return*, much less return to make that while-condition true? You stood up no windows, so only the application thread queue is there, and unless you're posting something to it that loop body will *never* be entered.

Comment: First (and *again!*) [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). After that read *all* of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question is being down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

`GetMessage` will wait for a window message from the window associated with the current thread. The wait is indefinite if there is no message, or no window.

If you do have a window, and message is generated, `printf` will be called as expected. But you should not put `printf` within the message loop. Instead respond to specific message in the window procedure.

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

int main()
{
    printf("hello world 1 \n");

    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(wcex) };
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "classname";
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
            0, 0, 300, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    MSG Msg;
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 )
    {
        printf("hello world 2\n");//<- don't put anything here in the message loop
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Barmak Shemirani, thank you for that !


 I am not a windows programming so this has kept me badly confused - the reason is I am using this in a deeply multi threaded setup for an app that needs to be compatible with windows. So I though I was making some crazy mistake somewhere or worse there was a race condition somewhere ! 

So thank you for making me feel at ease !